# rails simple_form remote: true dos not show validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, simple-form, zurb-foundation-6

i am stuck with a rails form in a foundation reveal with remote: true which does not show any validation errors.. any help is highly appreciated!

this is the reveal with the form:

```
<div class="reveal" id="new-trading-day-reveal" data-reveal>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>New Trading Day</h2>
  </div>
  <%= simple_form_for @trading_day, remote: true do |form| %>
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
      <div class="cell">
        <%= form.input :date, html5: true %>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <%= form.button :submit, class: 'expanded' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

and this is the relevant controller code:

```
class TradingDaysController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @trading_day = TradingDay.new
    authorize @trading_day
  end

  def create
    @trading_day = current_user.trading_days.create(trading_day_params)
    authorize @trading_day
    respond_to do |format|
      if @trading_day.save
        format.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
      else
        format.json {render json: @trading_day.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the controller does respond with a 422 (as expected) with the following reply:

```
{"date":["can't be blank"]}
```

though simple_form doesnt seem to pick that up to show the error...

i am glad for any help

thanks a lot guys,
Andreas

Comment: I believe you use the zurb foundation framework. I added the tag to the question. Please update the tag to reflect the version of the framework you use if you believe this can be helpful (there is zurb-foundation-5 and zurb-foundation-6).

Comment: If I remember correctly I had similar issues when using Ruby on Rails with the Foundation gem. Make sure your installation is correct. Also verify that the JavaScript code is executed at the right time (you might find questions and answers for that on StackOverflow).

Comment: foundation works without issues, its no foundation issue.. the reveal shows up, the data gets processed its just that the errors wont be shown in the simple_form